Why does the mesh disappear when I add a curve line node?
When I use the Curve Line node, my mesh disappears. I am trying to make the curve follow the start and end animation of the mesh.


You'll need a JoinGeometry Node in that case combining the output from the ExtrudeMesh and SetPosition nodes into your Viewer node or Group Output.


thank you very much :)

@AsmaAlkhaldi click the checkmark ✅ to accept the answer (you can upvote too)
